# Here api Consumer Free Plan expiration

Tags: here-api

Is there an expiration to the Free Plan for here.com javascript api services?
I am developing a demo product, and cannot afford the licence to expire after I deliver it. Yet, I could not find anywhere saying when the plan expires if it ever does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not Here API's customer support.

Comment: For what it's worth HERE's developer support pages point to SO as the support avenue, saying "their support staff actively monitors the here-api tag". But this specific question is probably more customer support than developer support - I would suggest contacting HERE via their contact link (https://developer.here.com/contact-us?interest=consumer-mapping).  They appear to have a Basic consumer plan that limits to 100k transactions per month and probably doesn't expire.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned previously there is the Basic Plan which can be used.If no plans available suit your requirement or you have queries regarding the plan, please reach out to HERE Sales team using the form on  [**here**](https://developer.here.com/contact-us?interest=consumer-mapping)